# How To Overwrite Files But Keep Original Files Timestamps

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have one folder "destination" where I have files and their time stamps (created, modified) I would like to preserve when I overwrite a few of those files with updated version of those files.

example

```
Destination Folder 
File.mp4- Created 01/01/01 (size 500mb)

Source Folder 
File.mp4 - Created 12/12/12 (size 4.00gb)
```

I overwrite the file in the Destination folder with the new updated version from the Source Folder but keeping the original file in the destination folder
timestamps

End Result (new overwrite file in the destination folder with original file timestamps)

```
Destination Folder
File.mp4 - Created 01/01/01 (size 4.00gb)
```

I have written a batch file to move the file as so

```
  robocopy "Source" "Destination" /E
```

and this handles my overwrites and moving of my files perfectly, but I haven't found a way to preserves timestamps. I am looking for command-line so I can implement it in a batch file. Any help will be appreciated. I been reading flags for robocopy etc but maybe I'm reading it wrong or something but I haven't figured it out yet.

EDIT:
This is the powershell code im working with but its not there yet.

edit 2 I deleted the power shell, idk what im doing.

Comment: Tagged as `Powershell` but there is no Powershell code? Powershell can `Get-ChildItem` and store the various timestamps then perform the file copy/overwrite and finally set the new files with the stored timestamps. See `PS C:\apps> Get-ChildItem .\new.log | Get-Member | where Name -like *time*` for more help

Comment: added powershell now, please take a look.

Comment: This cannot be the actual code you are using. This is so full of mistakes and omissions it can never work. Also, I see nothing of my answer in it. ? Please make an effort to show us the REAL code you are struggling with and edit this in a formatted way in your question.

Comment: I have just edited my answer because I may have mis-interpreted your question.

Comment: There is a windows API that allows you to set the create time...but you have to have access rights to do so. The Windows API is SetFileTime, which requires that the file be opened with FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES permission.

Comment: Please post the error messages of the code you are using, this is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is the `/copyall` flag.

```
robocopy "Source" "Destination" /e /copyall
```

This will be the same as if you had `/copy:DATSOU`

- D Data
- A Attributes
- T Time stamps
- S NTFS access control list (ACL)
- O Owner information
- U Auditing information

I would recommend you have a [read up on the flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) and how they work. But now you have a working example and can swap around the flags as you require!

Comment: But If my not mistaken that keeps the file I am Moving timestamps intact so it wont change to the time that it got moved/copy and thats not what I am after, I am trying to preserve the time stamps of the file I will be overwriting.and replacing and putting that timestamp on the new file I just moved over to replace that file.

Comment: Have you tried it? It copies the original timestamps on every system i have used it on in the last 12 months. Either that or just `/copy:DAT`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [System.IO.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It has number of methods you would want to use, such as `SetCreationTime`, `SetLastAccessTime`, `SetLastWriteTime` and etc. Like so:

```
#Creating new file
$File = New-Item -Path 'C:\file.txt' -ItemType File
#Getting the file's LastWriteTime attribute
[datetime]$LastWriteTime = [System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime($File)
#30 августа 2018 г. 9:34:56
"Changing file's data" | Out-File $File -Append
#Checkin the file's LastWriteTime attribute
[System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime($File)
#30 августа 2018 г. 9:35:49
#Now setting LastWriteTime attribute
[System.IO.File]::SetLastWriteTime($File, $LastWriteTime)
#Checkin the file's LastWriteTime attribute again
[System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime($File)
#30 августа 2018 г. 9:34:56
```

Comment: I tried it please take a look at the powershell code I added in OP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe you would like to keep the timestamps of the files in the source folder when the file does not yet exist in the destination also.
So:

- if the file is already present in the destination folder, copy and restore the time stamps from the file that existed in the destination
- if the file does not exist in the destination, copy from source and set the timestamps on the copy to match those from the original in the source folder.

If that is what you need, this is my edited code:

```
$sourceFolder      = '<YOUR SOURCE PATH HERE>'
$destinationFolder = '<YOUR DESTINATION PATH HERE>'

# get all the files in the source folder and loop through the list
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File | ForEach-Object {
    # combine the file name with the destination path
    $destinationFile = Join-Path $destinationFolder $_.Name
    # check if the file already exists in the destination
    if (Test-Path -Path $destinationFile -PathType Leaf) {
        # if exists, preserve the file time stamps of the existing file
        $existingFile   = Get-Item -Path $destinationFile
        $creationTime   = $existingFile.CreationTime
        $lastWiteTime   = $existingFile.LastWriteTime
        $lastAccessTime = $existingFile.LastAccessTime
    }
    else {
        # the file does not exist in the destination folder, so just copy
        # keep the timestamps from the source file? (Copy-Item will otherwise set a new CreationTime)
        $creationTime   = $_.CreationTime
        $lastWiteTime   = $_.LastWriteTime
        $lastAccessTime = $_.LastAccessTime
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destinationFile -Force
    # restore the original timestamps on the newly copied file
    $newFile = Get-Item -Path $destinationFile
    $newFile.CreationTime   = $creationTime
    $newfile.LastWriteTime  = $lastWiteTime
    $newfile.LastAccessTime = $lastAccessTime
}
```

Comment: looks promising but when tested it only just copies the files over doesnt preserve the time stamps. I added my powershell version to OP if you care to take a look